# How to remove the spacing between the triangle in C++?

Tags: c++, loops, switch-statement, nested-loops, void

Recently, I have written a shape generator to generate triangle and rectangle in C++. In this program, the rectangle function works fine as it does not have spacing between 'O'. However, for my triangle function, there is a spacing between 'O', no matter how I adjust, the spacing between 'O' could not be eliminated. For example, when the user inputs 5 as the height of the triangle, there will be a gap. This is the output shwon in my screen:

```
    O
   O O
  O O O
 O O O O
O O O O O
```

I expect to produce the output as shown:

[image: Output with no gap or spacing]

Is there any solution or suggestion to fix this issue? Thank you for your suggestion.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

void printTriangle()
{
    cout << "Enter height of triangle : ";
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int k = 2 * n - 2;
    cout << "\n\n";
    // open a file in write mode.
    
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("shape_generator.txt");
 
    // character to be printed
    char ch = 'O';
 
    // outer loop to handle number of rows
    // n in this case
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
 
 
    // inner loop to handle number spaces
    // values changing acc. to requirement
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++){
            cout << " ";
            outfile << " ";
        }
 
        // decrementing k after each loop
        k = k - 1;
 
        // inner loop to handle number of columns
        // values changing acc. to outer loop
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            // printing stars
            cout << ch << " ";
            outfile << ch << " ";
        }
 
        // ending line after each row
        cout << endl;
        outfile << "\n";
    }
    cout << "\n\n\n";
   
}

void printRectAngle(){
     int i, j, N, M;
    /* Input number of rows from user */
    cout << "Enter Height: ";
    cin >> N;
    cout << "Enter Width: ";
    cin >> M;
    cout << "\n\n\n";
    // open a file in write mode.
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("shape_generator.txt");
    /* Iterate through N rows */
    for(i=1; i<=N; i++)
    {
        /* Iterate over columns */
        for(j=1; j<=M; j++)
        {
            /* Print star for each column */
            cout << "O";
            outfile << "O";
        }
        
        /* Move to the next line/row */
        cout << "\n";
        outfile << "\n";
    }
    cout << "\n\n\n";
   // close the opened file.
   outfile.close();
}

int main()
{
        
        int option;
        do
        {
            cout << "Welcome to Shape Generator Service!\n\n";
            cout << "1.Triangle" << endl;
            cout << "2.Rectangle" << endl;
            cout << "0.Exit" << endl;
            cout << "Enter option : ";
            if(cin >> option)
            {
                switch (option)
                {
                    case 1:
                    system("cls");
                    printTriangle();
                    break;
                    
                    case 2:
                    system("cls");
                    printRectAngle();
                    break;
                    
                    case 0:
                    break;
                    
                    default:
                    cout << "The Option is Not Available." << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
            cout<<"Only Digits are Allowed! Press any key to continue..." << endl;
            getch();
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
            option = 15;
            }
                      
        }while(option != 0);
 
}
```

Comment: Do you know which line is responsible for printing the 'O'? Your problem lies within that.

Comment: The output you expect can't be done on plain terminals. It requires that you use a graphics library - or you _may_ be able to get close by using some UTF-8 half-step magic. Try creating the expected output manually, with your editor for example. It will probably not be easy.

Comment: @D-RAJ char ch = 'O';

Comment: You’ve [written this code](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/printing-the-triangle-pattern-using-last-term-n/), huh? Since you wrote the bit that added the space, why not just remove it?

Comment: The problem is I can't remove.

Comment: if u can answer please answer @Sneftel

Comment: @TEOHCHEEJIN  Do you have any questions regarding the answer you got or regarding my comment above?

Answer (score 2):

Here's something that *may* work, depending on your terminal capabilities.

Since your picture shows *half steps* on every other line you *may* be able to use the unicode U+2009 character *Thin Space* to indent every other line a little extra.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    auto thinspace = "\u2009";

    std::cout
        <<              "  O\n"
        << thinspace << " OO\n"
        <<              " OOO\n"
        << thinspace << "OOOO\n"
        <<              "OOOOO\n"
    ;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8E1bb76fh)

Note: This does *not* work in my own terminal window, but apparently it works on godbolt - so if this is good enough depends on where you are planning to display the result.